# see if local directory exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

```
print(os.path.isdir("~/.my_dir"))
```

the command should return True, if exists, and False, if not. **Anyways, it returns False if specified folder exists, or does not**.

```
dir = os.path.isdir('/.databases')
dirfile = os.path.exists('~/.databases/database.db')

if (dir == False):
    os.system('mkdir ~/.databases')
elif (dir == True):
    if dirfile == False:
        os.mknod('~/.databases/database.db')
        start()
    elif dirfile == True:
        db = ("~/.databases/database.db")
        main(db)
    else:
        print('Error 1')
else:
    print('Error 2')
```

That's the code i've been trying to fix for now 2 hours. it returns following error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/username/.databases’: File exists
```

Again, the problem is, that the command returns False whenever it needs to be True.

Comment: stop using ~ in your python code. Use the full, absolute path, always.

Comment: @JacobIRR I'm sharing the file, so i dont know the username . I want the directory to home directory

Comment: In case of Linux, you can use the environment variable `$HOME`.

Comment: it may be simpler to use the `-p` switch for `mkdir`, if available. e.g. `os.system('mkdir -p ~/.databases')` then you can (in this case) forget about whether it already exists or not

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `~` from the first path.

It should be:

```py
dir = os.path.isdir('~/.databases')
```

You can also simplify your if/else:

```py
if os.path.isdir('~/.databases'):
    print('dir')
else:
    print('not dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
dir = os.path.isdir('~/.databases')
dirfile = os.path.isfile('~/.databases/database.db')

if dir:
    if dirfile:
        db = ("~/.databases/database.db")
        main(db)
    else:
        os.mknod('~/.databases/database.db')
        start()
else:
    os.mkdir('~/.databases')
```

Comment: still, returns following "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/howl/.databases’: File exists"

Comment: What about this changed one?